# Proper way to add data in the R package

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2

I am creating a package with some data in it using `devtools` package. So far my package works perfectly for the functions that are stored in the package, however, I cannot make the data on the package to work.

I tried to follow the format used by Hadley in `ggplot2` documentation. I have a very simple data so far which has 6 rows and 2 columns.

I used the following documentation on a R file.

```
#' Jdutils Package
#' @name jdutils
#' @docType package
NULL

#' Sample state plane coordinates
#'
#' A dataset containing X coordinates and y coordinates in state plane coordinate
#' system in feet.
#'
#' \itemize{
#'  \item x_coord_as_numeric. X coordinate of the station
#'  \item y_coord_as_numeric. Y coordinate of the station
#' }
#'
#' @docType data
#' @name samplestations
#' @keywords datasets
#' @usage data(samplestations)
#' @format A dataframe with 6 rows and 2 variables
NULL
```

After creating a package and installing it, when I try to run the following command to load data I get the error.

```
> data(samplestations)
Warning message:
In data(samplestations) : data set ‘samplestations’ not found
```

I couldn't find the underlying problem. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

A data file `samplestations.Rda` is stored in the `data` folder of the package.

**Description of the package added**

```
Package: jdutils
Title: What the Package Does (one line, title case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("First", "Last", , "first.last@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph)
Depends: R (>= 3.1.0)
License: MIT
LazyData: true
Maintainer: Jan Dev <janesh.devkota@gmail.com>
```

Comment: how did you create the .rda (is it .Rda or .rda?). did you enable lazy loading?

Comment: Silly question but I"m assuming you used `library(yourpackage)` before this `data(samplestations)` call? And, to make explicit the last part of @rawr 's Q, I think it asking if you use `LazyData: true` in your DESCRIPTION. (This shouldn't affect the result of `data` call, however.)

Comment: I saved the dataframe as `save(df, file = "samplestations.Rda")`. I did use `LazyData : true` in the description. Yes, I did use `library(mypackage)` before using `data(samplestations)`. Not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: I added the description of the package in the post.

Comment: Problem solved. It seems the file format should be `.rda`. Thanks rawr.

Comment: Nice. If you include data in `package.skeleton` call, it seems `rda` used automatically. Same for `devtools::use_data`

Comment: maybe you could add that add your answer as  a real answer to this question? looking for "how to add data to a package" brought me here so it would be nice to have the answer directly!